# iOS block being stoped when view pushed

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, singleton, queue

The relevant part of my app consist of 2 views (view1 and view2), 1 operation (OP1) a singleton object (sObj), 1 queue and 1 BOOL. The singleton holds the queue reference and exposes OP1.

In view1 I start a OP1 async (it retrieves items for view2). I dispatch OP1 to the queue handled by "sObj" on view1 (the user fills the rest of the form and) press "next", push view2, view2 gets the "sObj" reference and checks if the operation completed, if yes, it fetches the results and display, if not, it goes to a loop checking the property "OP1Completed".

If the user is "slow" when choosing the options, theres a big chance that OP1 will complete before view2 is pushed, which is fine, and works perfectly! BUT if the user uses the defaults, there's a 99% chance that he will hit "next" before OP1 completed, which SHOULD be fine, but its not.

Checking logs and debugging I noticed that the async block running on the queue just stops running when view2 is pushed... and because of that "OP1Completed" flag is never set and then everything else on breaks...

can anyone help? i'm lost here!